# Custom headers for the WordPress plugin directory

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, readme

I just have submitted one of my simple WP Widget to the Wordpress Directory.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-twitter-trends/

I want to add  Plugin Title Image as like in http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/

How can I add that? From readme.txt file? How?

Comment: You are developing a plugin and haven't read the [Codex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/faq/)? . . . Bad boy :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple, 
All you need to create a image of size exactly `772×250` pixel and name it as `banner-772x250.jpg`. You have to save this image in `/assets/` folder in your plugins SVN directory.

- Make sure the image is of either `.png` or `.jpg` type.
- The `.gif` images are not allowed.
- It may take upto 15 minitues to appear on your plugin page.
- Another note - WordPress adds title to lower left corner of image.

Here is the example directory location and image name
`assets/banner-772x250.jpg)` OR `assets/banner-772x250.png`

[Link to official update](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/21/been-giving-a-lot-of-thought-to-how/) by matt (cofounder of wordpress )

Also, from the [Codex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/faq/):

> For development and testing, you can add a URL parameter to your plugin's URL of "?banner_url=A_LINK_TO_YOUR_IMAGE" to preview what the page will look like with your own image. This will only work with your own plugins, you can not use this parameter on anybody else's plugins.

Comment: And a retina version banner of size `1544x500` named `banner-1544x500.png` under the same assets folder

Comment: @Ashfame Do you have an official reference for this retina banner? So we can add the info to the Codex... Right now, there are only [4 occurrences](http://wordpress.org/search/banner-1544x500.png) searching wordpress.org

Comment: @Ashfame I couldn't find any official document about retina header-image support, link will be useful.

Comment: @amit check ottopress re retina image

Comment: Nice, one of the official plugin `jetpack` is using banner-1544x500.png image, you can see here - http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/jetpack/assets/

Comment: Here it is: http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/07/04/fun-with-high-dpi-displays/